Automatic matrix operations with parameters obtained by random numbers
I have matrix T defined by 2 parameters:
T = {{0, 0, 0},{0, 0, a},{0, a, b}};

These 2 parameters are randomly generated by means:
InputData = BlockRandom[RandomInteger[{-50, 50}, {10, 2}]]; (*first parameter is a, second parameter is b*)

I want to create a table in which each row corresponds to the following evaluation:



parameter a
parameter b
trace
determinant
first eigenvalue
second eigenvalue
third eigenvalue




...
...
...
...
...
...
...



How can I do this?

Det[T]==0 for all the values of the parameters.

First create a function that takes the parameters and creates the corresponding matrix:
fun[{a_, b_}] = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, a}, {0, a, b}};

Then create the matrices:
mats = fun /@ {{21, 
     18}, {-18, -25}, {-48, -29}, {7, -7}, {-32, -24}, {29, 20}, {-5, 
     45}, {-15, 35}, {-29, -47}, {6, -48}};

Now create the table content:
tab = {#[[3, 2]], #[[3, 3]], Tr[#], Det[#], t = Eigenvalues[#]; 
     t[[1]], t[[2]], t[[3]]} & /@ mats;

Finally add the headings and print it:
TableForm[tab, 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"a", "b", "Trace", "Det", "first EV", 
    "second EV", "third EV"}}]



Thanks! I've used the following code:
InputData = BlockRandom[RandomInteger[{-50, 50}, {10, 2}]];
fun[{a_, b_}] = {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, a}, {0, a, b}};
mats = fun /@ InputData;
tab = {#[[3, 2]], #[[3, 3]], Tr[#], Det[#], t = Eigenvalues[#];
t[[1]], t[[2]], t[[3]]} & /@ mats;
Dataset[AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "trace", "determinant",
"eigen 1", "eigen 2", "eigen 3"}, #] & /@ tab]
Unfortunately, the code generates different InputData vectors at every evaluation. How can I block InputData?

You may seed the random number generator by e.g. SeedRandom[n] where n is some Integer, e.g.: 1. Then, each time,  you will get the same sequence of random numbers.

It might be nice to create a helper function that builds a matrix from a parameter pair:
MakeMatrix[{a_, b_}] := SparseArray[{{2, 3} -> a, {3, 2} -> a, {3, 3} -> b}]

We can generate an intermediate structure that has the params and the resulting matrix in each row:
ParamsWithMatrices = Through[{First, Last, MakeMatrix}[#]] & /@ InputData

Then we can apply the functions you want to each matrix and do it "in place":
SubsetMap[
  Map[Through[{Tr, Det, Eigenvalues}[#]] &], 
  ParamsWithMatrices, 
  {All, -1}]

We need to appropriately flatten this to match your target structure exactly, so trying again:
Flatten /@ 
  SubsetMap[
    Map[Through[{Tr, Det, Eigenvalues}[#]] &], 
    ParamsWithMatrices, 
    {All, -1}]

(* this gives something like:

    {{9, 46, 46, 0, 23 + Sqrt[610], 23 - Sqrt[610], 0},
     ...
     {50, 16, 16, 0, 2*(4 + Sqrt[641]), 2*(4 - Sqrt[641]), 0}} *)

If we assign that to data, we can produce a nice dataset representation:
Dataset[AssociationThread[{"a", "b", "trace", "determinant", "eigen 1", "eigen 2", "eigen 3"}, #] & /@ data]


